# Running many devices on 5V pin. How to provide external power

Tags: power, arduino-due, current

I'm using my Arduino DUE 5V pin to power a lot of sensors and I'm worried about the drop in current.

I'm powering the board using the USB port. Is this the correct way or is there a different way of powering the board to make sure the current drop is limited as much as possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a maximum current you can use from the 5V pin(s), so it is good to split the current going into the Arduino.

You can use a breakout board for a USB, connect the USB to the breakout board, connect it both to the Arduino, and in parallel to the sensors; meaning the current used for the sensors is not going through the Arduino. You might need 2 break out boards, one for the input USB, one for the output USB.

Note there is a maximum current for USB too.